# getting the value of label in a cell in collection view in swift

Tags: swift, generics

I have a custom collection view where cell will have image and label
how to pass the value of label from the collection view to table view when the cell is selected in swift

Answer (score 0):

Use Delegate pattern to solve this.
As an example:

Check the sample code. Following sample is based on instance of UIViewController which opens an instance of UITableViewController. User can select on the TableViewController and it will be passed to the ViewController.

Protocol Code:

```
import UIKit

protocol SelectionTableViewControllerDelegate
{
    func selectionDone(controller: SelectionTableViewController, selection: Sting)
}
```

UIViewController Code:

```
import UIKit

class SampleViewController : UIViewController, SelectionTableViewControllerDelegate
{
    func selectionDone(controller: SelectionTableViewController, selection: String)
    {
        //use the selection as you wish
    }
}
```

UITableViewController Code:

```
class SelectionTableViewController : UITableViewContorller
{
    var delegate : SelectionTableViewControllerDelegate?

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPathindexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    let selectedValue = cell?.textLabel?.text

     self.delegate?.selectionDone(self, selection: selectedValue!)
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you to get an idea.

Comment: thank you for reply
but my question is how to get the value of label in cell of collection view not table view and send the the value to the next view

Comment: Just try the same thing with you CollectionView. What I was given is a sample that you can get an idea how you can overcome your issue.